# problem with 要 - it seems to have several meanings

Tags: meaning

一看见这些楼房，他心里就想，自己一定要买上一套房子。

This is the sentence that I've come across.  I've translated it as:

Once he sees these houses, he thinks that he can definitely buy a house himself.

But I'm always confused by 要.  I seems to have several meanings... 'to want to', 'will' and I suspect, in different contexts it has some grammatical meaning.

In this context it seems to mean 'will', though I'd always learnt 要 as meaning 'want to'.

Any guidelines here?

Answer (score 1):

I would translate `一定要` as "must":

*Seeing those houses, he thought, "I must buy myself a house!"*

`要` indeed has several meanings. I'm not sure I'd call that a "problem", but it can be challenging for a learner. I think the most basic meanings are "want", "must", and occasionally "will". Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

can definitely = 一定能

一定要 = must

Comment: aahhh, now I notice that perapera dictionary actually gives a meaning for this as a phrase... 一定能...  thanks

Comment: Arika, mind to add something more? Your answer triggered the low quality flag, make sure to write a meaningful answer (3 or 4 lines is enough).

Answer (score 0):

See these two pages for a more detailed explanation:

- [Wanting to do something with "yao"](http://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Wanting_to_do_something_with_%22yao%22)
- [Auxiliary verb "yao" and its multiple meanings](http://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Auxiliary_verb_%22yao%22_and_its_multiple_meanings)

To express "want to" one often uses the verb 想. For example *I want to go to the US / 我想去美国*. You can also use 要 in this sentence, but it completely changes the tone. In this case it might mean *I have to the US* or *I really want to go the US* or it can just be *I'm going to the US*, depending on the context. In general the tone is much stronger than for 想. For example if you want to express *want to have* you should use 要 and not 想.

As already mentioned 要 often indicates a firm tone. 一定 (meaning: certainly, must) makes it even stronger, so 一定要 can be translated as **must**.